# Show that a set of cluster points is closed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I don't know anything about topology, so please be kind. In a finite dimensional normed vector space $X$ I have a set $W$ with the property that for each $x\in W$ there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements in $X$ satisfying $x_n\to_{n\to\infty} x$.

I want to show that $W$ is closed (intuitively that should be true since it is a set of accumulation points right?). So I take any convergent sequence $\{w_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ of points of $W$ such that $w_i\to_{i\to\infty} \bar w$ for some $\bar w\in X$. It suffices to show that $\bar w\in W$. Since each $w_i\in W$ then I can find a sequence $\{ x_i^n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $x^i_n\to_{n\to \infty} w_i$. Thus I have:

1. For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_\epsilon>0$ such that $\|x^i_n-w_i\|\le \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.
2. For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M_\epsilon>0$ such that $\|w_i-\bar w\|\le \epsilon$ for all $i\ge M$.

Thus I define the sequence $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ with $\bar x_k := x^k_k$ and with $\nu>0$ arbitrary I fix $\epsilon=\nu/2$ and I set $Q_\epsilon:=\max\{N_\epsilon,M_\epsilon\}$, with $N_\epsilon$ and $M_\epsilon$ be defined accroding to 1-2. Then I have that for all $k\ge Q_\epsilon$ the following holds
\begin{align}
\|\bar w- \bar x_k\| &= \|\bar w- w_k +w_k -\bar x_k\|\le \|\bar w-w_k\| +\|w_k-\bar x_k\|\\&\le \epsilon + \epsilon\le \nu
\end{align}
and hence $\bar x_k\to_{k\in\to\infty} \bar w$.

Is this reasoning correct?
Thanks

Comment: What is a finite dimensional metric space?

Comment: I wanted to say that I'm considering spaces like n-dimensional Euclidean spaces rather than functional spaces such as L2.

Comment: Then why didn't you say it? Are we supposed to guess it?

Comment: Edited, is it clear now?

Comment: Is $\bar w=w$? Or is it another point?

Comment: typo. Sorry again, it is the same point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is false. *Every* set $W$ (closed or not) has the property that you mentioned. If $x\in W$, just define $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):x_n=x$. Then $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n=x$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is what one obtains by trying to transform a given problem into a new "self-contained" one that can be asked here and he does not know exactly what he is doing. A nonsense. I will try to set up a well-posed question. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer was useful, then perhaps that you could upvote it and/or mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: In my problem what happens is that not every sequence $\{x_n\}_n$  is admissible.. Thus the se W is defined by some given particular sequences that are admissible. $\{\bar x_k\}$ is admissible too.